# Base64 encoded string differs in perl and Java

Tags: java, perl, base64

when i encode a pdf file into base64 binary(using commons lib) in java , I got string(sample) like  "SGVsbG8gV_29y-bGQ="

But if i encode the same file using perl , I got like "SGVsbG8gV/29y+bGQ="

Difference in string: / instead of _ , + instead of -

**Why i am getting like this? Or, Is there any way to fix without string replace ?**

in java

```
byte[] data;
        try (java.io.FileInputStream fin = new java.io.FileInputStream(new java.io.File("file.pdf"))) {
            data = new byte[fin.available()];
            fin.read(data);
        }
        return data;
System.out.println("ecncoded value is " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data));
```

In Perl

```
use MIME::Base64;

open (PDF, "file.pdf") or die "$!";

$raw_string = do{ local $/ = undef; <PDF>; };
$encoded = encode_base64( $raw_string );

print " \n";
print " $encoded ";
```

// Java

[image]

// Perl

[image]

Comment: Where is your perl code. Please provide your code while asking.

Comment: @shivams added perl code

Comment: Did you try to test this with any other string. Is this same issue for almost every string?

Comment: @shivams Actually i am converting files into base64 string. I have tried with pdf, doc, rtf, txt files. All of them varies in perl and java base64 encode..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java code is giving you URL-safe base64, i.e the output can be used in URLs. The Perl version is not. You can blindly replace the characters with the other values.

Answer (score 0):

I am quoting wikipedia here `The particular set of 64 characters chosen to represent the 64 place-values for the base varies between implementations.`

This might be the reason for you to have different output with change in language. There are various implementations of base64 present out there and using various implementations might provide you different results.

My best suggestion is to stick to one kind of implementation. If you have to work with various languages then it is best to find compatible modules/libraries in both languages that use same implementation of base64. It might be good for you to have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: got it. http://search.cpan.org/~kazuho/MIME-Base64-URLSafe-0.01/lib/MIME/Base64/URLSafe.pm

Comment: @Prashanth good for you. Also i get to learn something new. :)